# Not able to connect Oracle (oci_connect) using PHP 5.6.3 (64 Bit) using Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8

Tags: oracle, iis-8

I am trying to connect to my Remote Oracle DB using PHP 5.6.3 (64 bit) using IIS as my Webserver and My Windows Platform is: Windows Server 2014 (64 bit).

I have downloaded the Oracle Instant Client 64 bit (instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip) on my 2012 server. Then I extracted them in E:folder (E:\Oracleclient) and also I had set the environment variable path E:\Oracleclient. Also in my PHP.ini I have commented extension=php_oci8_12c.dll (I don't see php_oci8.dll in the PHP 5.6.3, however I did try to download and copied in the extension folder but its not working).

My PHP Extension Path is also set properly under extension_dir and I have also set the environment variable path for the php where its located in c:

Then when I am using the code to connect to the data base I get this error:

```
The website cannot display the page

  HTTP 500 


Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error.


What you can try:



  Refresh the page.  



  Go back to the previous page.  



More information  More information
```

my code:

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('username','pwd','service:port/sid');
if ($conn) {

  echo "Connected to Oracle!";
}

oci_close($conn);

?>
```

I cannot share the connection details but yes the one which I am using to connect is correct.

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer? If there is an error there it might indicate what is missing. I am guessing it is not able to load the proper libraries.

Comment: Now I am getting the error message: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Oracle installation may not be fully valid from an IIS or PHP perspective.Unless you have a good reason not to do it, download and install a full Oracle Client 64 bit (as opposed to the instant client). That will take care of setting the PATH variable and creating any registry keys required by Oracle. Also, it will allow you to configure a TNS local name so you can connect to the database using a connect string like @MYPRODDB.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.. but I have noticed two things just wanted to share, in the PHPInfo Page under the Environment the PATH and PHPRC both are not changing they are showing the old values. However its using the right PHP.ini file under Loaded Configuration File.

Comment: You are welcome. Have you rebooted the host? Any service that runs under System will not pick up certain changes in the environment  until the machine is restarted.

Comment: Rebooted - used the ODBC Connection getting error "PHP Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 5: Access is denied. (Oracle in OracleInstantClient64, C:\inetpub\wwwroot\automation\OracleInstantClient64\SQORA32.dll)., SQL state IM003 in SQLConnect in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\automation\testqueryoc.php on line 2 PHP Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\automation\testqueryoc.php on line 4

Comment: Make sure that the Oracle directories have  read permission to  non-administrator users (possibly  SYSTEM, but you have to check which OS account is running the process that fails).